# Yii - Saving Data between 3 tables

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller, yii, saving-data

I am working with Yii and jQuery Mobile. I currently have 3 tables: Users, Projects and ShareProjects. I have been able to create a function to display shared projects with that user, but I am struggling to assign users to projects. I have tried this code but have been unsuccessful so far.

```
public function actionShareProjects() {  
   $model=new SharedProjects;
   if(isset($_POST['SharedProjects'])) {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['SharedProjects'];
      $model->project_id = "project_id";
      $model->user_id = "user_id";
      $model->sharedProject_id = "";
      $model->sharedCreateDate= date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
      if($model->save()) {
         echo json_encode(array('action'=>'success', 'message'=>''));
      } else {
          echo json_encode(array('action'=>'error', 'message'=>'Incorrect'));
      }
   }
}
```

In the project, there is a share button which takes the project id but I am trying to be able to allow the user to type an email in for the user you would like to share with.

I tried inputting it manually on postman but it failed, no errors came up but no data was saved. I used the correct input:

```
SharedProjects [user_id] 
SharedProjects [project_id] 
SharedProjects [sharedProject_id]
SharedProjects [sharedCreateDate]
```

Comment: can you show your model `SharedProjects` code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ABKJfFHV

Comment: Also in your model you set `array('project_id, user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),` in validation rules so it will fail because you are setting them `$model->project_id = "project_id";
      $model->user_id = "user_id";` to string instead of integer

Comment: Thanks, I have not used to much php or yii in the past. I am using it for a university project.

Comment: did it solve your problem? is it working now ?

Comment: Nope it didnt work.  I have tried a load of different ways. Basically I want to assign users to different projects. Which Is why I created the shared projects tables. Thanks

Comment: can you `var_dump($_POST['SharedProjects'])` and share the result

Comment: Postman came back with - Cache-Control - no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Comment: And there was no error when I ran function in the url

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
public function actionShareProjects() {  
   $model=new SharedProjects;
   if (isset($_POST['SharedProjects'])) {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['SharedProjects'];
      $model->sharedCreateDate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      if($model->save()) {
         $this->sendResponse(array('action'=>'success', 'message'=>''));
      } else {
         $this->sendResponse(array('action'=>'error', 'message'=>'Incorrect'));
      }
   }
}
```

and make sure `project_id`,`user_id` are set and are of `int` type. To play around sending `JSON` response better way would be adding this function

```
public function sendResponse($data)
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo CJSON::encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

in your controller and calling it for sending response.

Answer (score -1):

If no error is comes up then  your data is right for your model's rule validation but may be this is creating error while saving in database,

Have you applied any constraint(like unique , not null) on your table's column. They are also restrict to save wrong data in table.

Comment: First,  This is not an answer. Secondly you have enough reputation to post a comment.

Comment: sorry, but I think you don't know for commenting one should have 50 reputation. I tried to comment first before posting but it gives me a dialog "You must have 50 reputation to comment".